# When did Voldemort become active?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, hogwarts

The Sorcerer’s Stone was moved to Hogwarts at same time Harry took admission in the school. All things started happening in the same year.

Is it coincidence that Voldemort became active at the same time Harry joined Hogwarts?

Comment: Did you read the book(s) or just watch the movie(s)? Indeed: It seems to be pure coincidence.

Comment: Yes, I have done both.

Comment: It would have made a great plot point if Harry's magic power awakening also made old Voldy active again, since he is a horcrux.

But J.K. just left it as an odd coincedence

Comment: @GordonBennett After buying Harry Potter rights, I am going to hire you. We need to fix lots of things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## He became active once he had Quirrell.

The Dark Lord only became active again once Quirrell crossed his path, giving him the opportunity he needed to return.

> “Then … four years ago … the means for my return seemed assured. A wizard – young, foolish and gullible – wandered across my path in the forest I had made my home. Oh, he seemed the very chance I had been dreaming of … for he was a teacher at Dumbledore’s school … he was easy to bend to my will … he brought me back to this country, and after a while, I took possession of his body, to supervise him closely as he carried out my orders. But my plan failed. I did not manage to steal the Philosopher’s Stone. I was not to be assured immortal life. I was thwarted … thwarted, once again, by Harry Potter …” 
> <sub><sup>- *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

Before then, the Dark Lord had been waiting for either one of the Death Eaters to come find him or for some other chance to return.

> “I remember only forcing myself, sleeplessly, endlessly, second by second, to exist … I settled in a faraway place, in a forest, and I waited … surely, one of my faithful Death Eaters would try and find me … one of them would come and perform the magic I could not, to restore me to a body … but I waited in vain …’
>
> The shiver ran once more around the circle of listening Death Eaters. Voldemort let the silence spiral horribly before continuing. ‘Only one power remained to me. I could possess the bodies of others. But I dared not go where other humans were plentiful, for I knew that the Aurors were still abroad and searching for me. I sometimes inhabited animals – snakes, of course, being my preference – but I was little better off inside them than as pure spirit, for their bodies were ill-adapted to perform magic … and my possession of them shortened their lives; none of them lasted long …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

It’s only a coincidence that Quirrell crossed his path the same year Harry was starting at Hogwarts - his choice to return at that time was solely based on having Quirrell, and had nothing to do with Harry.